# When do P2Pool Node Fees get paid?

Tags: bitcoin-core, p2pool

I have set up a node and been running for a few days now and a couple of payments have gone out form it which is good.

These payments are going to a coinbase wallet and there is a local wallet configured for fees and the fee is set to 5%.

I have had 2 payment come out of the system at around 0.002 BTC but no fee payments have been sent to the p2pool wallet.

Are they held to reach a certain amount or are they computed in a different way that on the payout amount.

Thanks.

Comment: This is sorted too. 

Fee's are calculated based on Shares not in payout, so if you have a 5% fee you should get around 5% of the shares go to the pool.

Subject to variance of course.

Just leaving a comment as I can't answer the question yet........

Answer (score 1):

Correct - you will be awarded `node_fee` percentage of the shares found on your p2pool.

Relevant lines of code: https://github.com/jramos/p2pool/blob/master/p2pool/work.py#L197:L203